# Flash Builder Plugin Integration with Eclipse Indigo not working

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am new to Flex technology and trying to develop my first flex application, i need some help in setting up my workspace.

I am trying to build a sample application  explained in the below video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=se1JBZK9JXY

I have installed Eclipse Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Indigo, i also have installed Flash Builder separately and using the plugin install utility i have installed the Flash Builder plugin to Indigo eclipse for Jave EE.

The problem i am having is that when i bring up the Project Wizard , i dont see an option for Flash/Flex Projects. Can someone please tell me what i am missing here. I am using a MacOs 10.12.6

Thanks

Comment: What version of Flash Builder and did you try launching Flash Builder? And, under the Help menu, do you see any mention of Flash Builder?

Comment: Thanks AmigaAbattoir for your response, what i did was , i installed all the Web Developer Tools through install software options in Eclipse and its working fine now.